# writing validation function for listbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, customvalidator

I have a asp control listbox. And i have to validate this. This is described below:

```
<div style="float:top; width:300px">
  <span>Anrede</span>
     <asp:DropDownList  id="dropdownListAnrede" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid"
TabIndex="1"  Width="250px" BackColor="White" BorderColor="Silver" BorderWidth="1px" Height="22px">
          <asp:ListItem >Bitte auswählen</asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Value="Herr">Herr</asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Value="Frau">Frau</asp:ListItem>
          </asp:DropDownList>
          <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidatorAnrede" 
               **ClientValidationFunction=""** runat="server"
               ControlToValidate="dropdownListAnrede" ValidateEmptyText="true" SetFocusOnError="true" 
        ForeColor="Red" onservervalidate="CustomValidatorName_ServerValidate"> Wählen Sie bitte eine Anrede aus!</asp:CustomValidator>
</div>
```

I have to validate as if it dont have a value(Herr/frau) the sumission will not take place. and the error message will show the message is written in the text. I have to write a **ClientValidationFunction** in javascript. but I wonder how?

Comment: Did you [read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0z2h4sw.aspx)? That said, isn't a simple `RequiredFieldValidator` working in your case (as the first has no value)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a dummy value as the first item that's essentially no selection:

```
<asp:DropDownList  id="dropdownListAnrede" runat="server" ...>
    <asp:ListItem >-Select One-</asp:ListItem>
```

Get the drop down list, and check if it has a selected value greater than zero (omit the first).  This would be the clientvalidationfunction:

```
function val(sender, e) {
  var ddl = document.getElementById("<%= dropdownListAnrede.ClientID %>");
  e.IsValid = ddl.selectedIndex > 0;
}
```

Comment: as i know the ID ("dropdownListAnrede") can i directly place it in the JS function? How do I call the function? Do i have to sende peremeters(sender,e)?

Comment: Copy my val function directly into javascript, and take the name of the function "val" and add a property to the Custom Validator: `ClientValidationFunction="val"`.

Comment: If i select an item which has index greater than 0, will the error message disappear?

Comment: Thanks. Your code is working fine. except the first time. when i expand the dropdown but dont change my selection, there are no error message showing. I want to execute this action right from the first dropdownlist close event. what should i change?

Comment: It will still prevent postback of the page; when you go to save the form, the validation will appear, even though the * doesn't appear next to it.  You may have to manually invoke the validator using JavaScript if you want that to happen, as MS handles all of that for you and doesn't allow you to easily change the default functionality.  To invoke the validator manually, you can use the client-side ValidatorValidate or Page_ClientValidate.  To do that, check out this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx